# I have a problem on running my self coded app on Swift 10.2

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, sigabrt

Xcode says that there is a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT . Also it says libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) . I'm a beginner so please reply "easily" ;)

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        checkLocationServices()
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }


    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        }else{
            // show alert letting the user know he has to turn them on.
        }
    }


    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            break
        case .denied:
            // show alert instructing how to turn on permissions
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // show an alert letting them know what's up
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }
}


    extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            // later
            }
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            // later
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you connected the `mapView` outlet from your storyboard? (Do you see a filled circle in Xcode next to the property?). Do you see the location permission prompt?  Have you added the location usage description to your `info.plist`?  There should be an error message associated with the exception shown in the console

Comment: @Paulw11 yes everything seems to be good except the filled circle. It is not filled. But I connected it...

Comment: You are getting an error because you are telling the app to show user's current location on the map.  But the app is not ready to do so since you don't allow the app to access map view's delegate properties.

Comment: @ElTomato And how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Run a search for showsUserLocation and read other topics.

Comment: @ElTomato but it is because of missing this filled circle described by Paulw11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For circle to be filled (next to the `@IBOutlet` that connects UI control to the storyboard) you need to open both `.swift` file and the storyboard, try these to make sure its actually connected

- open storyboard file and then open `MapScreen.swift` file, the connector should be filled if its connected
- open storyboard file and click to show `Assistant Editor` so both storyboard and `MapScreen.swift` files are open parallel, also make sure you set Class to `MapScreen` in `Identity Inspector`, like in screenshot below

[image]

I will also list few suggestions concerning MKMapView and LocationManager

---

- `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` will not work, if `Info.plist` does not have one or more of following usage description

  ```
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Message for AlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>

  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Message for AlwaysUsageDescription</string>

  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>Message for WhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
  ```
- Once have permission to use location services, its necessary to ask `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` so you will get a location update through `CLLocationManagerDelegate`
- Location updates are received within `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)`, to be able to see user location on map, we need to set map region to that location, using `mapView.setRegion`

---

Here is the updated class

```
class MapScreen: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupLocationManager()
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        guard CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() else {
            // show alert letting the user know he has to turn them on.
            print("Location Servies: Disabled")
            return
        }

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorization(authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus? = nil) {
        switch (authorizationStatus ?? CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        case .restricted, .denied:
            // show alert instructing how to turn on permissions
            print("Location Servies: Denied / Restricted")
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
}


extension MapScreen: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.count > 1 ? locations.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp }).last : locations.first else { return }

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        self.checkLocationAuthorization(authorizationStatus: status)
    }

}
```

That yields

[image]